# How to add extra cell in cellForRowAtIndexPath?

Tags: ios, uitableview

For example, I have 3 articles and when I display articles I want to display one more cell before the first one (that would be then 4 total).

I need to display that first article which is not in array and then articles which are in array.

**UPDATE**

[image]

I have tried next:

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(
UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {

    return ([arr count] + 1);

}
```

But my app then crash sometimes and I see over NSLOG then that app enters cellForRowAtIndexPath before I call [tableView reloadData].

Answer (score 2):

This is something you should not really do.

Well, you can cheat the framework by returning a view (from -tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:) which would contain 2 subviews: your "first article" cell and the original first cell; don't forget to modify -tableView:heightForCellAtIndexPath: as well (otherwise your view would get cut).

But in general, you should change you data model behind the table view to dispay 4 cells – this is just a more valid approach.

Answer (score 1):

You can do like this :

**Return an additional row using this method :**

```
// Each row array object contains the members for that section
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section 
{
     return [YouArray count]+1; 
}
```

**At the end check for this added row :**

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
// Create a cell if one is not already available
    UITableViewCell *cell = [self.mContactsTable dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"any-cell"];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"any-cell"] autorelease];
         }

     //Identify the added row
     if(indexpath.row==0)
     {
        NSLog(@"This is first row");
     } 
     else{
      // Write your existing code

     }

}
```

Comment: I wrote in my first post (in update) that when I do that what happens.

Comment: @CroiOS When the app gets crash, what's the console prints?

Comment: Nothing. Table get's empty and that's all.

Comment: then why don't you put some check whether the object gets null i.e [NSNull null] or array count ? Also check for object whether the array still have the objects or you might be removing the objects from it.

Comment: Also put some code from where you are reloading your tableView.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a extra value in the array using `insertObject`

```
[arr insertObject:[NSNull null] atIndex:0];
```

And implement the methods like:

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [arr count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }
    if([arr onjectAtIndex:indexPath.row] == [NSNull null])
    {
      // 1st cell extra cell do your stuff
    }
    return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you keep all your articles in an array? You should add the new article to the array too. The array is your datasource. I take it that you'd want to insert the new article as the first element in your array if you'd like it to appear in the top cell. As soon as you've updated your array you should call `[mytableView reloadData]` which triggers all the datasource methods to be called and reload your table's data.

Comment: Yes, I keep all 3 articles in array. I updated my first post.